# Could habere in Latin and have in English (and other germanic languages) be cognate through proto germanic borrowing?

Tags: cognates

Have is said to come from the PIE word that means to keep. (Habere in latin also comes from PIE for to take.) I have been thinking that, because some words such as street have been borrowed from Latin into later Proto-Germanic, considering the similarities, could have come from Latin habeo/habere?

I think the b could have changed into f and then a v. The 2nd and 3rd happens from PIE *p a lot.

Comment: You actually don't need b > f > v. b > v is common enough on its own, without requiring the sound to change voicing twice.

Comment: In fact, b > v between vowels happened in Vulgar Latin! However, "have" has a well-attested PIE etymology, so there's no reason to suppose an extra borrowing.

Comment: While it is pretty clear that *to have* is not a borrowing from Latin (or later Romance) into Germanic, there is the possibility that *to have* has borrowed some of the meanings of Latin *habere*, a process named * Lehnbedeutung* ('semantic loan')

Answer (score 4):

English "have" is not cognate with Latin "habere" - even though they seem very close to each other.

English ["have" is from PIE *kap- "to seize, take,"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/have) cognate with Latin "capere." [Grimm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law)  shifted PIE *k to proto-Germanic *x, which became English /h/.

The Latin habere's etymology is a bit less attested, but might come from PIE *ghabh-, which also means "to seize, take."

Comment: German "ha**b**en" can't be regularly from \*kap-, don't be silly

Comment: "a bit lesd attested" has to be the understatement of the year. It is basically not reconstructable for PIE so poor is the evidence (as far as it is presented in wiktionary: celtic and Italic, also known as Celt-Italic; correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @vectory Do you know about Verner's Law?

Comment: @vectory - The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European says "Although *ghabh- is primarily attested in the West (e.g. O[ld]Ir[ish] gaibid 'takes,' Lat[in] habeō 'have,' Lith[uanian] gabenù 'present,' Pol[ish] gabać 'sieze'), it provides one of the Sanskrit words for 'hand' (gábastin-)" p.271.

Comment: Maybe wiktionary is more up to date, and maybe the root is not as wide spread as the Oxford Introduction to PIE claims, but I was using a different source, so had different information

Comment: There is no concensus. Derksen criticizes De Vaan for assigning \*ghebh to PSlav \*gabati next to Sanskr *gábhasti-* "hand, arm", Gothic *giban* "give", Lith. *gebeti*, *gabenti*, ... noting that these would fit \*gheHbh- (viz OIr. *gaibid*, Lat *habere*; with \*h2 the so called a-colouring laryngeal) as well and that "to a certain extent this classification seems arbitrary. I find it notable that various South Slavic languages have *habiti* listed as reflex. Sheer coincidence.

Comment: @TRK, that's quite serious. Yes, I should have known. But it implies *ha-* were a prefix. It fits that Derxen also indexed PSlav *eti* "v. *take*" (PIE \*h1m-), but there's so much more. I should pay more attention to accent (didn't copy them here, sorry).

Answer (score 3):

*Could* they? Sure, it's possible. "Yeet" could also be a borrowing from Proto-Western-Romance **jejt-*, which survived unattested in one obscure English dialect for several centuries before becoming famous in the era of Vine. **But it almost definitely isn't.**

In other words, quite a lot of things are technically *possible*. It's very hard to prove a negative. It's technically possible that Japanese and Arapaho are Indo-European languages, and it would be extremely hard to show 100% conclusive proof that they aren't—even though that theory is ridiculous and there's no evidence to support it. That's just the nature of science.

This is why Occam's Razor is important: the simpler explanation is often the better one. It's somewhere between difficult and impossible to prove that Proto-Germanic **xabjaną* existed before all contact with the Romans, because all our attestations of Germanic are post-Roman-contact. But we *can* say with good confidence that the PIE root **k-h₂p-* existed, and that if this root's **-ye-* present had survived into Germanic and gone through the usual sound changes, it would have come out looking exactly like **xabjaną*. This is a simpler explanation that doesn't require us to assume any loanwords, so Occam's Razor says it's probably the better one.

Comment: I guess this one is a popular one mainly because of the very analogous ways in which descendants of *habere* and descendants of *\*xabjaną* tend to be used, both as verbs for "have", and as auxiliary verbs for some kind of past tense and/or perfect aspect. That's a kind of Occam's razor, too, just from a different perspective. I'm not saying I don't believe in the accepted etymology, but it was one of those linguistics things that blew my mind a little when I first read about it, because I had always subconsciously *assumed* that the Latin and the Germanic *had* to share an origin. Yes I know.

Comment: @LjL A very good point! I assumed the same, until it was brought up as an example of Grimm's Law in some class or other.